# System Text JsonSerializer Deserialization of TimeSpan

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, timespan, system.text.json

In researching how to deserialize a `TimeSpan` using Newtonsoft's JSON.net I came across code in my current project that did not use Json.net. It used `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer` and **appeared** to not fail on the operation of deserializing the `TimeSpan` property, *as per the unit tests I was running*.

Great I thought, **.Net Core 3.1** has surpassed the *historical* issue of deserializing a `TimeSpan` and all is good. So fired up a test case in the latest version of Linqpad 6 (which uses .NET Core) to verify and to my chagrin it failed.

---

So the question is, can the `TimeSpan` be serialized/deserialized using either library (*and if so how*)… or is my test case below flawed in some respect?

---

**Code**

```
public class Project { public TimeSpan AverageScanTime { get; set; } }
```

**Linqpad C# Code**

```
var newP = new Project() { AverageScanTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(1) };

newP.Dump("New one");

var json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(newP);

json.Dump("JSON serialized");

System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Project>(json)
                               .Dump("JSON Deserialize");
```

**Deserialize Failure**

[image]

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [.Net Core 3.0 TimeSpan deserialization erro](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58283761/3744182), agree?

Comment: @dbc No, because that answer states that .NET core's json processing was *in-part* created to handle timespan but that not all timespan's are the same. I am talking a .Net's timespan as an input and it is failing....

Comment: *that answer states that .NET core's json processing was in-part created to handle timespan* - I don't see that.  The answer states, *The REST API service shouldn't produce such a JSON string.*  What's happening here is that the new serializer is just serializing all the properties of `TimeSpan` as a JSON object because it has no special case for that structure, then later failing to deserialize because all those properties are immutable.  A  `JsonConverter<TimeSpan>` like the one at the linked answer should resolve the issue.

Comment: Fixed in .NET 6.0
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69409726/11375591

Answer (score 23, accepted):

JsonSerializer for TimeSpan seem will added in [Future](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/24601) (removed from .NET 6 milestone). You can trace this issue in [Future milestone](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/milestone/1) or this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/24601).

Before the end of 2022, you need implement JsonTimeSpanConverter on your own. Or you can install [Macross.Json.Extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Macross.Json.Extensions/) nuget package and follow the [instruction](https://github.com/Macross-Software/core/blob/develop/ClassLibraries/Macross.Json.Extensions/README.md#timespans) to de/serializer.

At this time, with .NET 6, you can use the build-in Serialize method to serialize and deserialize objects. As below:

```cs
System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(
    new { Time = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100) }
);
// Output:
// {"Time":"00:01:40"}
```

Comment: Sadly, it has not been added to .NET Core 5. [Source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29932#issuecomment-694650687)

Comment: As of today it is moved to ["Future"](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/24601#issuecomment-856321283), so not in .Net 6 either.

Answer (score 5):

An addition to the answer from Poy Chang

Swagger (Swashbuckle) also requires a configuration

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.MapType(typeof(TimeSpan), () => new OpenApiSchema
    {
        Type = "string",
        Example = new OpenApiString("00:00:00")
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

TimeSpanConverter is available in .NET 6.0. So TimeSpan serialization/deserialization will work without custom converters out of the box.

Issue: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29932

Implementation: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/54186

Comment: How about an example of it working.

Comment: I don't think this is necessary for obvious code. But I agree with you that we can't believe everything that is written on the Internet and need to check everything))
https://dotnetfiddle.net/13kIUo

Comment: That is what happened with .Net 2/3, it kept getting reported that it now works...but it didn't. If you do have the example, that would be great.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. An example of what do you want? A working example for .NET 6.0 is here https://dotnetfiddle.net/13kIUo There is no built-in converter for the TimeSpan type in .NET 5.0 and .NET Core 3.1/3.0.