# Valid value for TimeSpan property to post in web api? C#

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, timespan

I have a TimeSpan property

```
public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
```

Currently using swagger to test API
Trying to figure out what value value to pass here

"time": {},

Tried:

"time": {"01:01:01"},

"time": {"01:01"},

"time": "01:01:01",

"time": 01:01:01,

all returning 401 code

Comment: 401 indicates the request lacks valid authentication credentials. Could you provide more details about what API you are testing, what kind of authentication it requires and how you’re creating the request?

Comment: What framework version do you use?

Answer (score 16):

On this another page you will find the solution to the problem: [.Net Core 3.0 TimeSpan deserialization error - Fixed in .Net 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58283761/net-core-3-0-timespan-deserialization-error-fixed-in-net-5-0).

In a complementary way, add this in the swagger

```
c.MapType<TimeSpan>(() => new OpenApiSchema
                {
                    Type = "string",
                    Example = new OpenApiString("00:00:00")
                });
```

Comment: Whole code is: 
services.AddSwaggerGen(
                    c => c.MapType<TimeSpan?>(() => new OpenApiSchema
                    {
                        Type = "string",
                        Example = new OpenApiString("00:00:00")
                    })
                );
That should be added in ConfigureServices, in Startup class.

Comment: But why does swagger  schema shows `{
  "TotalDuration": {
    "Ticks": 0,
    "Days": 0,
    "Hours": 0,
    "Milliseconds": 0,
    "Minutes": 0,
    "Seconds": 0,
    "TotalDays": 0,
    "TotalHours": 0,
    "TotalMilliseconds": 0,
    "TotalMinutes": 0,
    "TotalSeconds": 0
  }
}` this ? Any idea how to fix this ?